# Unable to open several (but not all) pdf files within mendeley desktop (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: pdf, mendeley

as the title says, Mendeley Desktop says "Unable to open PDF - It may be damaged" but I am able to open with external viewer by `Right click > Open File Externally`.

Edit: The same file opens in Mendeley's web version.

Comment: Updating to v.1.19.1 also worked for me. I noticed that mostly my articles in Spanish were the ones that couldn't be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with the Mendeley Desktop v1.19 on Ubuntu 18.04. 
Try update your Mendeley Desktop Version to v1.19.1. See [Release notes](https://www.mendeley.com/release-notes).

> Fix: PDFs not to open when the file name contained certain Unicode characters

Comment: thanks! If, for any reason, the user is not able to update Mendeley, one can remove unicode characters from the pdf filename (through the file manager and not within Mendeley).

Comment: thanks, going up to v1.9.1 of Mendeley indeed solved the problem